# CSS3 image slider, javascript navigation through slides not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've been trying to adapt the following code to integrate with my CSS3 slider (animated and timed with keyframes) however as you can't use .animate in js when using css3 animations on the same element I either have to use one or the other.

[JS I've adapted for my slider](http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery/page/5#comments)

The current js works in the sense that it navigates through the slides my only issue is that it doesn't 'slide' to each slide it jumps.

I'd really like to keep the slideshow as it is and just want to update my js so that the slide transition works. I'm not great with js so I've been finding it difficult to find a solution.
If anyone could give some advice or a solution to my problem it would be truly appreciated.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/1/)

JS

```
//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $("#carousel .video-list li").outerWidth();
var left_value = item_width * (-1);

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#previous').click(function () {
//get the right position            
var left_indent = parseInt($("#carousel .video-list").css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item
    $("#carousel .video-list").animate({'left' : left_indent}, function () {

    //move the last item and put it as first item                
    $("#carousel .video-list li:first").before($("#carousel .video-list li:last"));

    //set the default item to correct position
    $("#carousel .video-list").css({'left' : left_value});

    });    
//cancel the link behavior            
return false;
});

//if user clicked on next button
$('#next').click(function () {

    //get the right position
    var left_indent = parseInt($("#carousel .video-list").css('left')) - item_width;

    //slide the item
    $("#carousel .video-list").animate({'left' : left_indent}, function () {

    //move the first item and put it as last item
    $("#carousel .video-list li:last").after($("#carousel .video-list li:first"));

    //set the default item to correct position
    $("#carousel .video-list").css({'left' : left_value});
    });    
//cancel the link behavior
return false;

});
```

Comment: could you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I tried making one but kept going wrong somewhere, I'll try again.

Comment: Updated with a demo but can't seem to get the js to work in this jsFiddle. I know it definitely does work though, I'm clearly just missing something in this fiddle.

Comment: You are using jquery, need to set so in frameworks (first selector in the left)

Comment: Ah i see i knew it would have been something like that - I've updated that now so you can see it moves through the slides it just doesn't slide to them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why .animate is needed, because I have used

```
transition: left 1s ease;
```

in my CSS to achieve the same things, with a smoother animation than I got with jQuery.  I tried deleting the:

```
//slide the item
$("#carousel .video-list").animate(...
```

for the left and right.  I also added some text to the html divs so that you can see how it's moving better.  Sorry that I couldn't get it working, but I really feel that "transition" is what you need to look into.  Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sh3S/) :)

...

I think your simplest solution would be to ditch the whole CSS **animate**, and build your own carousel:
Consider a film strip, which is a bunch of pictures lined up next to each other.  Now consider a paper with a box cut-out, the size of one picture.  We put the strip behind the paper, and see only one image.  If we move the strip, we can change which image we see.

The film strip will be a **div** with **{ display: inline-block; }** property, containing each of the videos.  The box cut-out will be a **div** with **{ overflow: hidden }** property.  To move the strip, we simply use **$('#strip').css({'left': positionofstripleft - widthofbox })** in our javascript.  And for the animation, a simple **setInterval(Nextfunction, 65000)** to do what clicking next would do every 65 seconds.

Finally, a CSS **transition** will make the movements actually animated.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I need the transition to take effect when you click next/previous. e.g. click next and the slide eases towards the next slide. At the moment it is just jumping to the next slide. Can i ask what browser you're viewing it in? Is it definitely sliding when you click next/prev?

Comment: The slider is on a timer so that it goes round the carousel but I wanted the option to navigate so i added the next/prev buttons. Im looking at your fiddle and its still just jumping to each slide and not easing to each slide on click?

Comment: Let me ask an important question.  When I am on item 1 and I click "Next" to go to item 2, what things actually change position, and where exactly do they go?

Comment: Ok so I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/2/ to make it easier to see. Each colour block represents a video (I'm using HTML5 videos) Basically if you click next on item one it goes to item two - I want it to transition: ease 1s for example to that slide. Does this make sense?

Comment: Really sorry I've only just seen your update. So you suggest making the css keyframe slider into a jQuery slider?